# Why is my android studio app working in API 34, but not API 33 and below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, geolocation

I am trying to make an app that will get the current user's location in terms of latitude and longitude and generate a notification containing the coordinates. However, my app works in API 34, but not API 33 and below, even after downgrading the dependency versions, the build completes, but there is no output when clicking the button.

Here is the MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.velvetthunder.driverlocation

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_CODE = 101
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var currentLocation: Location

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fetchLastLocation()
        }

    private fun fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        task.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                currentLocation = location
                findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
                    .setOnClickListener {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${currentLocation.latitude},${currentLocation.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLastLocation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.velvetthunder.driverlocation"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.velvetthunder.driverlocation"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DriverLocation"
        tools:targetApi="33"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my first time using Android Studio, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if the location permission is enabled when its downgraded to 33?.
Confirm it by looking at the phone settings -> apps -? Permission

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: I believe that the problem lies with the "fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation" part, since the true code in conditional statement to check if the location is null is not being reached, however, I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

You are not requesting COARSE permission.

You should first request COARSE permission.

And once you obtained it go for FINE

Comment: Thank you, the solution worked perfectly after replacing FINE location with COARSE location in the MainActivity.kt file.